# Php 7 with laravel 5.5.40 mongo db laravel provider issue

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, composer-php

Any one have idea about the below issue, so please suggest me:

`composer update jenssegers/mongodb`

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1

```
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.4.0 requires illuminate/database ^5.6 -> satisfiable
 by illuminate/database[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6
.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5
, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your composer.lock file and open up composer.json.
Change laravel version to 5.6.*
Then perform a sudo composer install again.
That'll solve your problem.

Happy Coding.

Comment: You're right composer shouldn't be run as sudo but when you're using an ec2 instance, it'll help a lot.

Comment: No, it does not help, but hide the real problems on your system